# Including server names in file paths

Tags: terminal, finder, path, url

We have two servers, `ServerOne` and `ServerTwo`. Each server contains a folder called Projects. On Windows, the paths to each of these folders are `\\ServerOne\Projects` and `\\ServerTwo\Projects`, respectively. On a Mac, the paths instead are `/Volumes/Projects` and `/Volumes/Projects1`. Depending on which order a user accesses the `Projects` folder from each server through the Finder, either one might be `Projects` or `Projects1`. Neither will be available through /Volumes in the Terminal until accessed through the Finder. Is there a reason for this behavior? Is it possible to include the name of a server in URLs so the path is absolute and more easily shared across platforms?

Comment: Instead of mounting the Projects folder, can you mount the  server (ie mount /ServerOne instead of /ServerOne/Projects)? (The only problem is if the system administrator doesn't allow you to mount that point.) Then your paths would be /Volumes/ServerOne/Projects and /Volumes/ServerTwo/Projects.

Comment: You can use `/etc/fstab` to tailor the mountpoints, just [as you would on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) (with a few differences such as the [use of `vifs`](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930150059172). There are a few more methods [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100403050702737).